# how can i get turtle to draw a web spiral?

Tags: python

im trying to get my turtle to draw a spiralling spiderweb but i just cant get the spiral to spiral or to loop until it hits the edge. ive tried several different things but i cant work it out. im pretty new to coding :)

```
from turtle import *
from math import sin, cos, pi
from random import randint
shape("circle")
turtlesize(0.3)
speed(5)
n=int(input("give number of main lines: "))
r=int(input("give length of main lines: "))
spiraldistance=r/10
angle=360/n
rad=(pi*angle)/180
for i in range(n):
    forward(r)
    backward(r)
    right(hoek)
x=cos(rad*0)*spiraldistance
y=sin(rad*0)*spiraldistance
goto(x,y)
integers = []
for j in range(0, r):
    p = 10/n
    integers.append(j)
    integers.append(p)
    x=cos(rad*j)*(spiraldistance+p)
    y=sin(rad*j)*(spiraldistance+p)
    goto(x,y)

input("Press enter to finish")
```

i need it to spiral this way look at the screenshots

https://gyazo.com/028228823b7aab611db144436cf93868

https://gyazo.com/5c9ca19cfa34be5559bdbc3365f65f0d

pls help :(

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework question. If you want us to help, show us what you already tried and where specifically you failed. We're not here to help you solve your assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Inside loop you have to change `p` but you always use the same value

```
p = 10/n
```

If you use `+=` instead of `=`

```
p += 10/n
```

then you can get spiral

---

Example code:

```
from turtle import *
from math import sin, cos, pi

shape("circle")
turtlesize(0.3)
speed(0)

#---

#n = int(input("give number of main lines: "))
n = 5
#r = int(input("give length of main lines: "))
r = 200

#---

angle = 360/n
for i in range(n):
    forward(r)
    backward(r)
    right(angle)

#---

spiraldistance = r/10
rad = (pi*angle)/180
p = 0

for j in range(r):
    x = cos(rad*j) * (spiraldistance+p)
    y = sin(rad*j) * (spiraldistance+p)
    goto(x, y)
    p += 10/n

exitonclick()
```

---

Result for `n = 5`:

[image]

Result for `n = 15`:

[image]

**EDIT:** To stop spiral before end of lines which have leght `r` you would have to compare `spiraldistance+p` with r` - ie

```
if spiraldistance+p >= r:
    break
```

Or better use `while` loop for this

```
spiraldistance = r/10
rad = (pi*angle)/180
p = 0
j = 0

while spiraldistance+p < r:
    x = cos(rad*j) * (spiraldistance+p)
    y = sin(rad*j) * (spiraldistance+p)
    goto(x, y)
    p += 10/n
    j += 1
```

---

**EDIT:** I added `steps` to choose how many times spiral "cross" every line.

```
from turtle import *
from math import sin, cos, pi

shape("circle")
turtlesize(0.3)
speed(0)

#--- settings ---

# number of main lines
#n = int(input("give number of main lines: "))
n = 15

# length of main lines
#r = int(input("give length of main lines: "))
length = 200

# number of steps on every main line
steps = 15

#--- main lines ---

angle = 360/n
for i in range(n):
    forward(length)
    backward(length)
    right(angle)

#--- spiral ---

p = (length/n)/steps
rad = (pi*angle)/180

spiraldistance = 0
j = 0

while spiraldistance < length:
    spiraldistance += p
    x = cos(j) * spiraldistance
    y = sin(j) * spiraldistance
    goto(x, y)
    j += rad

#--- keep open ---

#mainloop()
exitonclick()
```

Steps 5 and 15:

[image]

Comment: @aminkamal `x += 1` **is the same as** `x = x+1`, so you are adding to the existing value. If you do `x = 1` you replace the value without adding to what was before.

Comment: thank you, what is the difference between = and +=? cant i make it stop before spiralling out of the web range? hopefully you see this

Comment: as @BrunoLubascher already said `=` assigns the same value to `p` in `p = 10/n`  so later you have always the same value in `(spiraldistance+p)` so you always get the same values in `x,y`. But `+=` works like `p = p + 10/n` so in every loop you have different value in `p` so you you get different value in `(spiraldistance+p)` and you get different values in `x,y`

Comment: to stop spiral before end of lines which have length `r` you can check `spiraldistance+p >= r` and exit loop using `break` - ie. `if spiraldistance+p >= r: break` . OR you would have to use `while spiraldistance+p < r:` instead of `for`-loop.

Comment: ty furas, but if i increase the amount of lines the spiral only goes until half the web. the more lines i have the shorter the spiral. anyone know how to counter this?

Comment: as I said before - you have to check `spiraldistance+p < r` instead of using `for`-loop - and it works for any number of lines. I even add some code in answer.

Comment: wow didnt see srry. thank you i have a better understanding thanks to you

Comment: sadly it doesnt seem to work if n<10 for some reason

Comment: `n` never change so there is no sense to use it.

Comment: I tested my code and it works for `n=5` and `n=15` - for other values it should works too.

Comment: BTW: I added code which uses variable `steps` to choose how many times spiral should cross mail lines - see image below code.

Comment: ah i see ty, srry i cant go to chat yet for this hahaha. and if i add a randint how would i go about giving the spiral some randomness